# Use value from Input and set it to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-events

I have an Input that takes a name, and I want to take that name from input and set the url accordingly .. Here's the code, and an example

```
.form-group
            %input.form-control{'type':'name','placeholder':'Name',id:'wisher_name'}
            %input.form-control{'type':'name','placeholder':'Special Message'}
            %button.btn.btn.btn-success{'id':'wisher_btn'} Wish
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '#wisher_btn', function() {
     var e = document.getElementById("wisher_name");
     var diwali_wisher = e.value
     location.replace("localhost:3000" + "/loccasion/diwali/" + diwali_wisher);

   });
 });
```

But the last statement is never reached, I don't know why?

This is a very basic problem, but I am a beginner so need some help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a full url, like  *https://stackoverflow.com*.

Add the http protocol.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. first... its localhost I'm working on, second it doesn't even reach the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

`diwali_wisher=`  Input parameter name in receiver function

```
diwali_wisher = e.value
location.replace("localhost:3000" + "/loccasion/diwali?diwali_wisher=" + diwali_wisher);
```